# BREXIT: leaving the EU with a second passport

Tags: dual-nationality, brexit

I had entered Italy before Brexit and have a long-term visa here as a British national. However, I also have a Malaysian passport and am wondering since there is no stamp in my UK passport, would it be possible for me to leave Italy using my Malaysian passport to have it stamped since there was no entry stamp in my UK passport anyway?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to have my Malaysian passport stamped as Malaysia does not recognise dual nationality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Comment: Won’t an exit stamp in your Malaysian passport without a corresponding entry stamp be a red flag for the Malaysian authorities? Where are you flying to from Italy?

Comment: Not sure about that as technically the entry stamp might be in a different passport? I plan to fly out of Milan Malpensa.

Comment: Thanks for the link @lambshaanxy. I have read it and understand that the general rule is we enter and exit a country using the same passport. However, this is a unique situation where there is no entry stamp as the UK was part of the EU when I entered with my UK passport. If the passport control do not check for the entry stamp upon exit at Milan Malpensa then technically i could use any passport as long as its a valid passport?

Comment: Are you flying to Malaysia from Italy?

Comment: Yes, I plan to.

Comment: What different passport would an entry stamp ‘technically’ be in? If you mean an expired Malaysian passport, that would imply that the issue date of your current Malaysian passport would have to be less than 90 days before the exit stamp? If it’s older than that, how would you account for a missing entry stamp, having entered as a visa-free national?

Comment: It normally doesn't get to that detail at the border. If they investigate then there's no running away. Having an answer to "where are you flying from" at this point is my priority. Without an exit stamp from any country would be even more difficult to explain. Alternatively I have a 2 hour layover at Abu Dhabi in which I can get my passport stamped.

Comment: @Afifz regarding getting stamps at the layover in Abu Dhabi - I'd be concerned that entry and exit stamps from the same day may raise more questions than they answer. Is there some third country you could stop off in for a few days, rather than hours? Of course, that may be more expensive and is anyway more difficult at current time than it would usually be. But it would give you a legit answer to 'where are you flying from?', solve the 'no exit stamp' issue and avoid the 'exit stamp with no corresponding entry stamp' issue.

Comment: Thanks @Chris H. That is a good option to consider. O will look into that but given the realities of travel during COVID times it will be alot more complicated than usual with the whole PCR test and quarantine requirements that some countries require. Will definitely look into it though.